# Should users immediately report to admins when they receive a windfall of serial upvotes?

Tags: discussion

I received a run of 14 upvotes for my 14 highest ranking answers yesterday, at virtually the same time. Today 9 of the votes were expunged. Even so, that leaves me with 5 upvotes that seem too good to be true (that is, not earned by the usual system of carefully considered one-by-one voting).

The automated explanation for the removal of the 9 upvotes very politely reassured me that everything was being taken care of, skullduggery was not suspected, etc.; but I wonder whether (1) I should have reported the run of upvotes to someone in the EL&U administration as soon as I noticed them, and (2) whether the remaining 5 serial upvotes not yet stripped out of my current total constitute some sort of threshold acceptable windfall (or a nice parting gift or something of that nature), or whether they too should be retracted—and perhaps will be in the fullness of time.

Can anyone clarify the responsibilities of a beneficiary of serial upvoting who would like to be a (reasonably) good citizen about this type of thing, especially in the event that (as in my case) the automatic retraction of the upvotes covered only part of the total bonanza? Thanks!

Comment: This question has been addressed before, e.g. [here](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/4163/). Count it as karmic restitution for 5 undeserved down votes. It happens occasionally and no one will complain if you keep them. Otherwise mods will have to do all kinds of work to create balance in the cosmos.

Comment: Prior to there, it was addressed [here](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/q/3241/2303).

Comment: Jon Ericson, Community Manager, has answered [here](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/4166). All moderators can do is use tools to show suspicious patterns and then refer them to CMs for disposal [that is, either reversal of serial votes or leaving alone]. As the script has done its stuff, I wouldn't worry too much about it until it happens again. The thing to do then is to raise a flag for moderator attention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your responsibility in such cases is to not worry about it, let the automatic processes take care of what they wish to take care of, and enjoy the remaining reputation/badges. :)